# Bulkifying a trigger or send everything in a Future method (with a callout inside)

Tags: apex, trigger, callout

I would like to anticipate a "mass update" of my accounts. I need to bulkify my code which contains a Callout.

What happens when a mass update is done ? Like importing a list of account. 
Is the trigger called multiple times or one time with a list ?

I need to know to develop the best solution due to callout and limitation.

In the trigger I could handle a list and make a final callout, but handle the list inside the trigger (synchronious) with a huge data would make it "lag" no ?

Or, what I did is directly calling my future method in the trigger :

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after insert, after update) {

FutureTaskCreator.sendNotificationTest(JSON.serialize(Trigger.new), JSON.serialize(Trigger.oldMap));

}
```

And handleling everything :

```
@future(callout=true)
public static void sendNotificationTest(String listAccountsString, String oldAccountsString){//List<Account> listAccounts, Map<Id, SObject> oldAccounts
    List<Account> listAccounts =(List<Account>)System.JSON.deserialize(listAccountsString, List<Account>.class);
    Map<Id, SObject> oldAccounts =(Map<Id, SObject>)System.JSON.deserialize(oldAccountsString, Map<Id, SObject>.class);

    List<Account> lstJson = new List<Account>();
    lstJson.addAll(listAccounts);
    for(Integer i=0;i<lstJson.size();i++){
    //stuff
    }

    if(lstJson.size()>0){
      Map<string, List<Account>> accountMap = new Map<string, List<Account>>();   
        accountMap.put('items', lstJson);
     HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    Http http = new Http();
    System.debug('The Json STRING'+JSON.serialize(accountMap));

    String endpoint = 'https://85915fe6.ngrok.io/api/Person';

    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;');
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    //req.setTimeout(20);
    req.setbody(JSON.serialize(accountMap));

    try {
        HTTPResponse response = http.send(req);
        System.debug(res.toString());
    } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
        System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
        System.debug(res.toString());
    }
    }
    }
```

What I don't like is implementing the post method within the function and not separately.

Should I keep my code as so ?

Comment: Triggers can be called with up to 200 records per Transaction (up to 2000 in Platform Event use cases). Delegating to async is required as triggers can't do callouts. A given transaction has limits on callouts so chained queueables or delegated batch is required.  Dan Appleman's `Advanced Apex` book has a pattern that scales to millions

Comment: @cropredy Thanks for the info ! What do you call a "given tansaction" ? Since I am sending the full list of Accuonts and handle it in the Future method, I shouldn't reach any limit no ?

Comment: Inside my trigger I should directly call a queuable job passing all the data needed ?

Comment: Benoit - there is a limit on #callouts per transaction and if the trigger passes 200 records to the future (which is its own transaction), you'll exceed that limit (plus others like total callout time). You need to delegate `n` records in the trigger to `m` async transactions such that any async transaction doesn't exceed limits

Comment: Thanks, as you can see in my code I create a list from the Accounts triggered (max 200) So I will callout Once for one list of 200 (the list is post as parameter). `req.setbody(JSON.serialize(accountMap));` Whatever I write as code : the Trigger will be fire by packet of 200, so I should write code to handle the list to not reach any limits in Callout (50) or Queue(50 chained and only One Callout inside). So I created a list and I will callout once with the list. Am I doign the right thing ?

Comment: @cropredy My final question : Should I create the list inside the Trigger or should I pass my `Trigger.New` and `Trigger.Old` with other parameter inside a Future function where I create the list ? Like I did in my question : `trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after insert, after update) {

FutureTaskCreator.sendNotificationTest(JSON.serialize(Trigger.new), JSON.serialize(Trigger.oldMap));

}`